# Order of layered JInternalPanes

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jinternalframe

I have some JInternalFrames in a JLayeredPane. Assume that the JInternalFrames are in the same layer of the JLayeredPane. Say that the JInternalFrames overlap in this layer. Anyone have an idea of how I can tell which JInternalFrames are ontop, and in what order they are layered?

Thanks

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624885/how-to-get-the-z-order-of-jinternalframes-in-a-jdesktoppane

Comment: Yes it has. That works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the ZOrder of the component.